# Animation on click

Tags: css

I just started fooling around with CSS. Im trying to make an animation (menu drop down) that should trigger on a button click. I found a good example, but in triggers on the hoover event and changes the style of a couple of divs.

I guess I need to set the style when my button is clicked, and then change it back when it is clicked again. But I cant get it to work.

Here is the CSS:

```
            /* Static state */
            #container  { 
                width: 400px; 
                height: 400px; 
                position: relative; 
                border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            }
            .parent1    { 
                /* overall animation container */
                height: 0; 
                overflow: hidden;

                -webkit-transition-property: height;
                -webkit-transition-duration: .5s; 
                -webkit-perspective: 1000px; 
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 

                -moz-transition-property:height; 
                -moz-transition-duration: .5s; 
                -moz-perspective: 1000px; 
                -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 

                -o-transition-property: all; 
                -o-transition-duration: .5s;
                -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
                -o-transform-origin: top;

                transition-property: height;
                transition-duration: .5s;
                perspective: 1000px;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
            }
            .parent2    { 
                /* full content during animation *can* go here */ 
            }
            .parent3    { 
                /* animated, "folded" block */
                height: 56px; 

                -webkit-transition-property: all; 
                -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
                -webkit-transform-origin: top; 

                -moz-transition-property: all; 
                -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
                -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
                -moz-transform-origin: top; 

                -o-transition-property: all; 
                -o-transition-duration: .5s;
                -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
                -o-transform-origin: top;

                transition-property: all; 
                transition-duration: .5s;
                transform: rotateX(-90deg);
                transform-origin: top; 
            }

            /* Hover states to trigger animations */
            #container:hover .parent1   { height: 111px; }
            #container:hover .parent3   { 
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
                -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
                -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
                transform: rotateX(0deg); 
                height: 111px; 
            }
```

And here is what I been working on.....

```
            <script>
            function fold()
            {
                var element = document.getElementById('parent1');
                element.style.height= 111;

                element = document.getElementById('parent3');
                var prop = getTransformProperty(element);
                element.style[prop] = 'rotateX(0deg)';
                element.style.height= 111;
            }

            function getTransformProperty(element) 
            {
                // Note that in some versions of IE9 it is critical that
                // msTransform appear in this list before MozTransform
                var properties = [
                    'transform',
                    'WebkitTransform',
                    'msTransform',
                    'MozTransform',
                    'OTransform'
                ];
                var p;
                while (p = properties.shift()) {
                    if (typeof element.style[p] != 'undefined') {
                        return p;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are a lot more likely to get a response if you make a JSFiddle :)

Comment: Im still stuck here. Does anyone have any tips? http://jsfiddle.net/larsa2000/58QjK/

Answer (score 0):

You could save a lot of time and effort using  -
[jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible)

```
<script>
$(function() {
            $(".accordion").show().accordion({
                heightStyle: "content",
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                animate: {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
                },
            });
        })
</script>
```

Note that you can style this plugin any way you like,

```
.accordion {/* some style*/}

.ui-accordion-content {/* some style*/}

.accordion h6 {/* some style*/}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/M3mEX/) that shows how I've abused the accordion widget.

Answer (score -1):

HERE IT IS EASY : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amirm3hdi/5mKra/embedded/result/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something Else</li>
    <li>Another Thing</li>
    <li>Or This</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>

<h3>
    Dropdown Example -
    <a href="#">Amir Mehdi</a>
</h3>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("div , li").click(function () {
    $("ul").slideToggle(120);
});
```